# Is a bus bar needed?

Tags: electromagnetism

For a short period of time, *10 kA* must flow in a circuit, is a bus bar needed? I mean, since the flow of current duration is less than **0.010** seconds on a certain wire?

Comment: I think this questions needs more context, while plenty of heavy duty cable could handle that duty cycle from a practical point of view it depends on what voltage drop could be tolerated in a particular application.

Comment: What do you mean by the voltage drop here?

Comment: Voltage drop? There will be less voltage at the load than at the input to the circuit : this difference is the voltage drop. If you need at least 2V at the load, and your supply provides 3V, you must keep the voltage drop below 1V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a little spreadsheet and play with some numbers.

Given a length of copper, its cross sectional area, and resistivity, you can calculate its resistance.

Now there are two aspects of the cable's performance to consider:

- Voltage drop, calculated from V=IR.

If the voltage drop is excessive, increase the conductor's area.

- Temperature rise.

Given the resistance, you can calculate power dissipation P = I^2*R at 10 kA.

Given the mass of copper (length * area * density) and its heat capacity, you can calculate the rate of rise in temperature for the specified current.

As a first step, neglect cooling, assume all the heat energy increases the temperature.

Energy = power * time = mass * heat capacity * dT.

Or, dT = I^2 * R * time / (mass * heat capacity)

Or, dT = I^2 * length * resistivity * time / (mass * heat capacity * area)

If the temperature rise is unacceptable, (perhaps, more than 20K rise in temperature) increase the conductor's area. If the temperature rises above the melting point of copper, that's not a circuit, that's a fuse.

At this stage I am assuming the duty cycle is low enough that temperature returns to ambient before the next pulse. You can ensure this if necessary by measuring the conductor's temperature and preventing further pulses otherwise.

**Note** - repeat these calculations under worst case conditions : what happens if the current isn't cut off after 10ms because of a fault elsewhere?

Comment: Well I found a reasonable busbar, that's resistance is 40 micro-ohms, and did all the calculations it seems the heat increase is 15K, so It safe to use this busbar?

Comment: With certain caveats, it could be safe. These include: how good are the connections TO the busbar? can it cool between pulses? can you guarantee the current will cut after 10ms or reasonably close? does the design remain safe (current is limited) if the load is short circuited? And probably other aspects like the mechanical forces mentioned by Spehro. This is NOT something you can expect a StackExchange answer to guarantee, but it sounds like you might be on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Brian Drummond's answer is correct and complete, I'll just add some observations-- that kind of current and duration is common in resistance welding such as spot and capacitive discharge welding. Usually there is a maximum resistance spec that must be met, such as 0.001 ohms. You can calculate that for a wire from the diameter and resistivity of copper at a given temperature, but it's easier to just look it up in a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge). For example 4/0 wire has a resistance of 0.16m\$\Omega\$ per meter.

I have some experience with a small precision CD welder that has a big brother in that category. Since the weld heads must move, they do indeed use fat cables with many strands. The actual energy transfer is only about 1000J maximum at several times per second maximum (most of which goes into the weld) so heating is not a problem. You should do the calculation Brian suggests for your rep rate and energy loss to see how many watts are being lost in the conductors.

One thing that may not be obvious is that for short pulse lengths you should dress the wires together and bind them with cable ties to minimize the inductance. There will be some magnetic force pulling the wires together during the pulse.